# How to copy HTML web source code to excel with special characters

Tags: html, excel, vba

So i have this code, it strips the whole HTML source code to next cells in a columns. The problem is that the web page that I use to extract the HTML source code have some Polish letters like "ą","ś" and so on.
Is there a way to paste the code with those Polish letters ? Now I'm getting some crazy squares with question marks and so on. Any tip ?

ps. I have this code thanks to @pizzettix https://stackoverflow.com/users/6254609/pizzettix

```
Sub audycje()
    
    Dim strona As Object
    Dim adres As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim a As Object
    Dim str_var As Variant
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    adres = InputBox("Podaj adres strony")
    If adres = "" Then
       MsgBox ("Nie podano strony do zaladowania")
    Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set strona = CreateObject("htmlfile")   'Create HTMLFile Object
    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")  'Get the WebPage Content
       .Open "GET", adres, False
       .send
       strona.Body.Innerhtml = .responseText
    End With
    
    'Split_with_delimiter_newline
    split_var = Split(strona.Body.Innerhtml, Chr(10))
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(split_var, 1)
       Cells(2 + i, 2).Value2 = split_var(i)
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a month of search I've finally got it !
The below code does the trick :)

```
Sub audycje()
    Dim strona As Object
    Dim adres As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim str_var As Variant
    Dim Mystring As String
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    adres = InputBox("Podaj adres strony")
    If adres = "" Then
       MsgBox ("Nie podano strony do zaladowania")
    Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set strona = CreateObject("htmlfile")   'Create HTMLFile Object
    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")  'Get the WebPage Content
       .Open "GET", adres, False
       .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
       .send
       strona.body.innerHTML = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    
    'Split_with_delimiter_newline
    split_var = Split(strona.body.innerHTML, Chr(10))
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(split_var, 1)
    wb.Worksheets("Dane").Cells(2 + i, 2).Value2 = split_var(i)
    Next i
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: I see my suspicions confirmed as far as the character coding is concerned. But I don't understand why it didn't work with your previous code. Especially since you now specify `UTF-8`, but the document is encoded with `WINDOWS-1250`. But I am glad that you have finally reached your goal :-)

Comment: Zwen, it's a mystery to me as well, I've got so frustrated that I was just trying anything. Anyway thank you very much for your time :) !

Comment: I will look into this again when I find the time. For now, the important thing is that it works for you. But I would like to know what it is all about. I will look for pages with different charsets and experiment with them. Also because I want to know why it reproducibly comes to an endless loop with certain pages.

Comment: Zwenn fell free to let me know if you've found anything

Answer (score 0):

What ever you want with HTML in an Excel sheet. The datatype `String` can't handle UTF-8 characters. But you can detect every `CHR(10)` and with a few string operations it is possible to write every line of HTML code directly from the `responseText` to the current cell. Not even an HTML document is needed:

```
Sub audycje()
    
  Dim adres As String
  Dim currRow As Long
  Dim posFrom As Long
  Dim posTo As Long
  
  currRow = 2
  adres = InputBox("Podaj adres strony")
  If adres = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Nie podano strony do zaladowania")
    Exit Sub
  End If
  
  With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp.6.0")  'Get the WebPage Content
    .Open "GET", adres, False
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/plain"
    .send
    
    If .Status = 200 Then
      posFrom = 1
      Do
        posTo = InStr(posFrom, .responseText, Chr(10))
        If posTo > 0 Then
          Cells(currRow, 2) = Mid(.responseText, posFrom, posTo - posFrom)
          posFrom = posTo + 1
          currRow = currRow + 1
        Else
          Exit Do
        End If
      Loop
    Else
      MsgBox "Page not loaded: HTTP Status " & .Status
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: the above code replaces the Polish characters with a space bar. 
And tends to loop for ever, so I had to force code to stop running. 

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">` not sure if that may help, but it's @ the beginning of the whole source code 
I've been stuck with this for like a month, and still cant figure it out why I can't copy  those special characters ;/

Comment: @HasztagWojt I have tried this with various Polish sites. First with an offer from allegro.pl, then with 2 other sites that don't mean anything to me because I don't know Polish and finally with the site audi.pl The Polish letters were always transferred correctly into the Excel cells. I also had the problem with the endless loop with one of the two unspecified pages. In this respect, I can half understand your feedback. I had hoped that you would use a page where the infinite loop did not occur. Can you tell me the URL?

Comment: @HasztagWojt Please have a look at the HTML code. You should find something like this at the top of the head `<meta charset="utf-8">`. Maybe you have a different encoding than UTF-8.

Comment: i can give you the URL but you won't be able to open the site as you need my corporate connection to open it ;/ 
But, as you can see, I've just posted an answer, I've just cracked this issue :) 
Anyway many thanks, for help, rly appreciated !

Comment: Zwenn i have sth like that
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html; charset=WINDOWS-1250">`